# UITableViewCell + standard disclosure indicator + secondary UIButton + HIG violation

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton, hig

I've a simple question but I cannot find a clear answer around the web.

Suppose I have a custom

```
UITableViewCell
```

With the default disclosure detail button that take to a detail view controller.

Is it good to have secondary, custom button that, when tapped, fires another action rather than presenting the detail view controller?

Or it could be an HIG violation?

any suggestion very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Where would you like to put another button? Maybe the simplest thing to do is put the other action in

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

I probably mis-explained.

Here is a raw image. It may help claryfing the question:
[image]

Comment: After googling and watching hundreds of iOS common patterns, I come to a conclusion: having an UIButton on a selectable UITableViewCell may not violate any Apple HIG, but it's a very very bad experience for the user.